# phpMailer - localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a very simple HTML CSS and javaScript website on my localhost. I want to do a very simple contact form. Normally I use WordPress through a plugin to achieve this and have never manually created emails in a plain website.

I have downloaded the class.phpmailper.php file from: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php and put it in the root of my site.

On my contact form I do a simple

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}
```

and try to send an email. I have put in the same SMTP details that I use on my WordPress websites, however when I click submit the page just says:

**The website-name page isn’t working**

**envirofuel-redesign is currently unable to handle this request.**

**HTTP ERROR 500**

This is the code that is executed when the form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

    $subject = 'test';
    $body_of_your_email = 'hello test body';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                       // telling the class to use SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    // 0 = no output, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only.

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "";              // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "I PUT MY SMTP HOST HERE";        // sets Gmail as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 587;                     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL

    $mail->Username = "I PUT MY USERNAME HERE";  // Gmail username
    $mail->Password = "I PUT MY PASSWORD HERE";      // Gmail password

    $mail->CharSet = 'windows-1250';
    $mail->SetFrom ('info@example.com', 'Example.com Information');
    $mail->AddBCC ( 'sales@example.com', 'Example.com Sales Dep.');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
    $mail->IsHTML(false);

    $mail->Body = $body_of_your_email;
    // you may also use $mail->Body = file_get_contents('your_mail_template.html');

    $mail->AddAddress ('I PUT MY PERSONAL EMAIL HERE', 'Matthew');
    // you may also use this format $mail->AddAddress ($recipient);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        $error_message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else
    {
        $error_message = "Successfully sent!";
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: ERROR 500 is a server-level error. What are the logs saying? Do you have any debugging tool running?

Comment: You've based your code on an obsolete PHPMailer example. Update it. The error you're getting (which will be in your web server logs) is probably that you have not loaded the SMTP class.

Answer (score 0):

If your Wordpress websites are able to send emails, your email server settings should be Ok.

You may need to configure your php to use SMTP, try adding before all:

```
ini_set('SMTP','localhost' ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'email_account_you_want@your_domain.com');
```

If it works then you can modify your php.ini in order to make these settings global.

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
sendmail_from = email_account_you_want@your_domain.com
```